# How does Metamask revert/cancel minting transactions?

Tags: transactions, metamask, wallets, nft

I unfortunately wasn’t able to find any information on this, neither on Metamask's community forums nor anywhere else online. I’m wondering how minting transactions are cancelled through Metamask or similar wallets.

I understand that with “normal” transactions, you can create a reverting transaction with the same nonce but higher gas fees in order to cancel the initial transaction. How does this work with mints? Is a "normal" transaction with the value of 0 ETH send to cancel the minting-initiation?

Thank you so much for your help! I’m just interested in how NFTs and blockchains work on the technical level

Answer (score 3):

As you may have learned, Metamask cancels a transaction that has not been mined by replacing it with a transaction where you send 0 ETH to yourself.

This method works for cancelling any transaction, including NFT minting transactions that have not been confirmed in a block.

---

If you want to replace a transaction yourself by manually setting the nonce of your replacement transaction, you have to remember that the gas price you set needs to be at least 10% higher than the gas price of the transaction you want to replace.  (For an EIP 1559 transaction, both the max priority fee, and max fee, need to be 10% higher.)